# Is the construction "[only/merely/just + infinitive]" grammatical?

Tags: conjunctions, parallelism, only

Consider this sentence:

> I am not going to the dinner, merely to the cocktail hour.

Is this grammatical? Why? It's a little like a coordinating conjunction, except that the elements aren't parallel -- that is, the intended meaning is the opposite of this:

> I am not going merely to the cocktail hour.

Comment: It's an _elidation_ or omission of unnecessary words. The sentence could be written "I am not going to the dinner, _I am going merely_ to the cocktail hour". This can be, and sometimes is, used but the elided form is much more common.

Comment: Yes, it sounds fine to me. But that is a bit simplistic. Can you elaborate on really what you want to know here? Is this a particular dialect that you asking about? How to parse the whole thing? What the meaning really is? Please edit your question to specify.

Comment: "only" seems more idiomatic than "merely", especially in the second sentence.